# How to create nested DTO class in NestJS corresponding to Schema

Tags: mongodb, nestjs

I am new to NestJs and trying to create nested schema in Mongoose as I want this data structure in my database:

```
{
  name:"John",
   age:28,
  address:{
     city:"Delhi",
     state:"Delhi
  }
}
```

For this I have created below mongoose schema:

**user.schema.ts**

```
import mongoose from "mongoose";

export const UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({

 name:{type:String},
 age:{type:Number},
 address:{
     city:{type:String},
     state:{type:String}
  }
});
```

How Can I write Dto class for this schema.Someone let me know As I want to add data inside database.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply create two DTO classes in the following way.

```
export class AdressDto {
    readonly city: string;
    readonly state: string;
}
export class UserDto {
    readonly name: string;
    readonly age: number;
    readonly address: AdressDto
}
```

In the official Nestjs [documentation](https://docs.nestjs.com/controllers#request-payloads) you can find how to use DTO
in your controllers, and you can also find how to use [validators](https://docs.nestjs.com/pipes#class-validator) if you want to use them.